# ffmpeg add alpha channel to a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Basically I have a video with a green background, and I mean a perfect green background (red = 0, green = 255, blue = 0) and I want to convert this to alpha (i.e add an alpha channel where 0 255 0 corresponds to alpha)

I am very new to ffmpeg so I can't figure this out. I am guessing it has something to do with the alphamerge or color channel mixer option but I can't understand the syntax.

The docs have given this example for color mixer:

```
colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3
```

But I dont know get what exactly is going on here. same goes for the alpha merge example:

```
movie=in_alpha.mkv [alpha]; [in][alpha] alphamerge [out]
```

Don't get what that means^^

THanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to convert the green channel to alpha with full transparency? Not sure I understand the requirement.

Comment: @death_relic0 I am not sure either. Do you mean the output RGBA to be `0 255 0 255` (both green and alpha highest values) or `0 0 0 255` (no green value but highest alpha value)? The former one is `colorchannelmixer=aa=0:ag=1`; the latter one is `colorchannelmixer=gg=0:aa=0:ag=1`.